# Как добавить атрибут disabled в input`ы

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Суть задачи в том что на странице есть куча инпутов. Их по ТегНейму нужно сделать выключенными. Конструкция getElementsByTagName('input').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled') не работает - вылазит ошибка. Но вот самое интересное что через ById работает, но очень не практично прописывать везде идишки. Подскажите пожалуйста что не так?

```js
function check_disable(){
  var block_input = document.getElementsByTagName('input').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
}
```

```html
<div class="answer">
  <div class="left">
   <input type="radio" name="a2" id="right1">1 вариант ответа<br/>
   <input type="radio" name="a2">2 вариант ответа<br/>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
   <input type="radio" name="a2">3 вариант ответа<br/>
   <input type="radio" name="a2">4 вариант ответа<br/>
  </div>

 </div>
  
  <button onclick="check_disable()">Check disable</button>
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName('anwser')`  возвращает набор дом елементов, а `setAttribute` это функция дом елемента, по этому и дает ошибку, вам нужно по етой колекции пройтись циклом и поставить дизейбл каждому инпуту отдельно, например так : `[...document.getElementsByTagName('input')].forEach(i => i.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled'));`

Comment: упс* там должно было быть не классНейм а тэгНейм. Сейчас попробую Ваш код. отпишусь

Comment: Я либо неправильно пишу, либо чет не то(

Comment: ошибки в консоле есть ?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/nqb6ap
держите. Вопросик по квадратным скобочкам, я немного не понял как они должны стоять

Comment: квадратные скобки это спред оператор, в данном случаи он превращает псевдо масив в масив, и стоять они должны в точности, как я написал в первом коменте )
ПС: вместо спред оператора можно юзать функцию `Array.from` ну или перебирать елементы простым циклом

Comment: Конструкция должна выглядеть таким образом? 
var block_input = [document.getElementsByTagName('input')].forEach(i => i.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled'));

Comment: ну скопируйте же то что я в комментарии писал , после первой квадратной скобки троеточие

Comment: ааа, я то думал что это должна быть моя переменная)) спасибо, работает)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var bubu = ['moo', 'kuku', 1529, 'doo'];
```

Вот эта фигня называется массив... А элементы массива можно получить так:

```
bubu[0] // = 'moo'
bubu[1] // = 'kuku'
bubu[2] // = 1529
bubu[3] // = 'doo'
```

Если вы записали

```
var bubu = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
```

Оно "За кулисами" берет и пихает все найденные элементы в массив. Чьи элементы ровно также можно будет получить по номеру. `bubu[0]` - будет первый такой тег на странице, `bubu[1]` - второй и т.п.

Поэтому если хочется вырубить все инпуты, нужно пройтись по всем номерам, например так:

```
function check_disable(){
  let bubu = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  for( let i = 0; i < bubu.length; i++ ){
    bubu[i].setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    //Или bubu[i].disabled = true;
  }
}
```

Цикл for берет и кругами выполняет всё, что написано внутри... на первом круге i = 0, на втором круге i = 1 и т.д., перебрав все элементы.

---

А в комментарии выше:

```
[...document.getElementsByTagName('input')]
```

Взят пустой массив `[]` - в который через троеточие можно сверху напихать элементы какого-нибудь другого массива (в данном случае, найденные элементы input). Подобная запись просто короче.